# How can I replace all strings wrapped by colon in a string using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, regex

I want a regex to speed up the search of replace of smilies in my app using jQuery.

**Example: Here is the input text**

Hi :smile: I feel strong today :muscle:

**Problem**

How to search :smile: and :muscle: automatically using regex and replace them if they are found in string?

I would like to get the matches also e.g.

```
content.replace(/\[([^\]]+)\]/g, '<img .. $1 >');
```

Note: Basically, I didn't try any solution cause I didn't find any by searching on google. I found many for [bbcodes] like that, but none for colon :string: I am sorry

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Please include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. Thanks!

Comment: Basically, I didn't try any solution cause I didn't find any by searching on google. I found many for [bbcodes] like that, but none for colon :string: I am sorry

Comment: so take the solutions you found for `[bbcodes]` and try altering it to fit your needs. at least try it.

Comment: It's ok but you need to give it your best shot before asking for help. That way you can learn way better. Hope you will understand that programmer here are not sitting here to write full length code for others but to guide them in right direction..

Comment: Please guys excuse me, I didn't mean to be rude or not doing my homework but really regex is not my thing I am very sorry. I'll try now thanks for your help :)

Comment: No offence bro. We are always here to help. Just give it a try few times and post that code here. There onwards many can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this sample: *also in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kha29xer/)*

```js
function wr(msg) {
    document.write(msg + "<br/>");
}

var txt = "Hi :smile: I feel strong today :muscle:";
    
wr("Original text:");
wr(txt + "<br/>");

var matches = [];
txt = txt.replace(/\s?:[^:]*?:/g, function (match) {
    matches.push(match);
    return "";
});

wr("Replaced text:");
wr(txt + "<br/>");

wr(matches.join("<br/>"));
```

---

Based on this regex:

`\s?:[^:]*?:`

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/fV8lB3/1)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You might do this:

```js
var re = /(:\w+:)/g;
var str = 'Hi :smile: I feel strong today :muscle:';
var match = str.match(re);

var newstr = str.replace(re, function(item) {
  var slice = item.slice(1, -1);
  //return slice;
  // just for a demo you can use this.
  if (slice == 'smile') {
    return '<img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/musthave/16/Positive.png">';
  } else {
    return '<img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/sport-items-2/512/gym_dumnbell-16.png">';
  }
});

document.querySelector('span').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(match);

document.querySelector('strong').innerHTML = newstr;
```

```html
<span></span>
<br/>
<strong></strong>
```

---

In fact you can do this to replace each word with a img. In this snippet i assume all the icons are in `.png` ext.:

```
var newstr = str.replace(re, function(item) {
  var slice = item.slice(1, -1);
  return '<img src="your/path/to/smilyes/'+slice+'.png">';

});
```